# Create a private namespace independent of other javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a script which may be used on a variety of websites. Since I don't know the circumstances of it's use, I'd like to be able to place it in a sandbox of sorts, where it does not affect other javascripts on the page, and is in turn not effected by other javascripts.

The most basic start is using a self-invoking function:

```
(function(){
   x = function(){ alert('hi!');
   x();
})();
```

But my problem is that if x is already assigned as such, you cannot override it:

```
x = function(){ alert('too late!');
(function(){
   x = function(){ alert('hi!');
   x();
})();
```

This will alert "too late!" rather than "hi!", which is not my desired effect. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't forget to use the `var` statement, if you don't use it the variable will be declared in the global scope. You're on the right track though, create your own scope within an immediately executed function. For example:

```
var x = function() { alert('foo') };
(function() {
    var x = function() { alert('bar') }
    x() // 'bar'
}());
x() // 'foo'
```

Going back to your example:

```
x = function(){ alert('too late!')};
(function(){
   x = function(){ alert('hi!')};
   x(); // 'hi'
})();
x(); // 'hi'
```

This will alert 'hi' twice, because without the `var` statement you are working with the same `x` value in both scopes. If you were to use the `var` statement inside the self-executing function, the second invocation of `x` would alert 'too late!'.

Comment: Thank you sir! For the longest time I could not identify my folly. It was a simple act of a misplaced right parentheses! Where as a self-executing function ending in `})();` works, `}());` is the correct use! In this context, the addition of `var` makes little difference.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases you forgot to add `}` after part with `alert()`.

Check out this fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/XSebK/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/XSebK/2/) - it actually works as you expected and the code looks like this:

```
x = function(){ alert('too late!'); };

(function(){
    x = function(){ alert('hi!'); }
    x();
})();
```